# VMAgent Unresponsive

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, azure

One of my VM's just became unavailable and I am not able to connect. I have deallocated/reallocated, redeployed, and reset password. Nothing works.  How to I get the VMAgent to reset so I can connect again?

When I execute this:

```
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "SP-SVR1" -Status
```

I get the following. Note the VMAgent's Level property is Warning and that the message is "VM Agent is Unresponsive"

```
ResourceGroupName          : MyResourceGroup
Name                       : SP-SVR1
BootDiagnostics            :
  ConsoleScreenshotBlobUri :
https://diagstoreeonatynishp64.blob.core.windows.net/bootdiagnostics-svrl...
Disks[0]                   :
  Name                     : SP-SVR1
  Statuses[0]              :
    Code                   : ProvisioningState/succeeded
    Level                  : Info
    DisplayStatus          : Provisioning succeeded
    Time                   : 11/8/2017 11:43:27 PM
VMAgent                    :
  VmAgentVersion           : Unknown
  Statuses[0]              :
    Code                   : ProvisioningState/Unavailable
    Level                  : Warning
    DisplayStatus          : Not Ready
    Message                : VM Agent is unresponsive.
    Time                   : 11/9/2017 12:06:30 AM
Statuses[0]                :
  Code                     : ProvisioningState/succeeded
  Level                    : Info
  DisplayStatus            : Provisioning succeeded
  Time                     : 11/8/2017 11:47:21 PM
Statuses[1]                :
  Code                     : PowerState/running
  Level                    : Info
  DisplayStatus            : VM running
```

Comment: can you RDP to that VM now?

Comment: no i cannot RDP to the machine which is the reason for the post.

Comment: Could you please download VHD to local Hyper-v, and configure it?

Answer (score 0):

> How to I get the VMAgent to reset so I can connect again?

Can you RDP or SSH to that VM now?

If you can login that VM, we can upgrade or re-install VMAgent.

If your VM is windows, we can follow this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/vm-agent-and-extensions-part-2/) to re-install it.
If your VM is Linux, we can follow this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/agent-user-guide) to re-install it.

If you can't login to that VM, maybe we can download the VHD to local Hyper-V to install or upgrade Azure VM agent.

Also, we can try to delete the VM and **keep the VHD**, use that VHD to re-create a VM, in this way, Azure VM agent will running.

Comment: can this be done via PowerShell remote?

Comment: @ChiliYago I think we can't do it by PowerShell, because agent seems down, Azure platform and Azure VM communicate with Azure VM agent. Could you download it to local?

Comment: I ended up restoring a snapshot.  I had little time for all these steps.  Hopefully MS will find a easier way to do this in the future.